# Is this possible to do? Playlists + Youtube Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-channels

Im wondering if is possible to do this. Anywhere on my view I want to see a list of videos (from my youtube channel or just a playlist created by me), this way the user can click in any of them and using the youtube player API would be visualizated in the bottom of the screen for example.

Is this possible to do and if so, how complicated could be? (im really a beginner in android, not in programming). Ive read about Youtube DATA APi but it seems is used with the youtube app so its not what I want to do.

Thanks a lot.

**Editing 21/05/2014**

Adding information just in case someone in the future is interested in doing this (after one year, but better later than never). I uploaded an exemplary app that shows how to do this. It can be found in the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/Rafagf/HealthTube

Comment: The YouTube Player API will let you play a playlist.

You can use the Data API v3 to get all the images and titles in a playlist to display in your layout.  

In Android, you'll probably want to create a ListView with a custom layout.  What would you like more help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [the examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications)? That's the best place to get started. I don't think anyone is going to be able to provide you with more complete code than what's available there.